# How to make multiple HTTP GET requests based on previous future responses in Scala?

Tags: scala, http, get, future

I have several functions that have to make a GET request to a REST API. To get the code working, I need to make these calls synchronously as I have to pass some parameters that belong to the previous response.

Imagine I have this function:

```
def getLocations(region: String, key: String): List[(Int, Int, String)] = {

    // ************1.*************
    val getLocationsURL = url("https://api.transitfeeds.com/v1/getLocations?").GET <<? List("key" -> key)

    val response: Future[String] = Http.configure(_ setFollowRedirects true)(getLocationsURL OK as.String)

    //Evaluamos respuesta de la página
    response onComplete {
      case Success(content) => {
        //Make json
        val json = (parse(content) \\ "results" \\ "locations").children

        for (loc <- json) {

          //Extract all locations
          val locations = loc.extract[List[Locations]]

          /*
          val countries = (locations.filter(w => w.t.contains(inputCountry))).map((x=> (x.id, x.pid, x.n)))
          println(countries) //id, pid, n. Now we already have the list of regions interested in
          */

          val regions = (locations.filter(w => w.n.contains(inputRegion))).map((x => (x.id, x.pid, x.n)))
          println(regions) //id, pid, n. Now we already have the region interested in (only 1)
          finalRegion = regions

        }
      }

      case Failure(t) => {
        println("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)

      }
    }
    return finalRegion

  }
```

Now I need the result of `finalRegion` to be inserted in another function that will make another HTTP GET request (almost the same as what is shown above), but I receive an error because the first future is not completed yet.

Answer (score 0):

### The issue here

What you are trying to do here is to return a result which is not computed yet. The `onComplete` is actually called after the function has returned the result. (By the way, I think that you've forgotten to initialize your varable `finalRegion`)

It is the wrong way of seeing thinks in Scala. The idea is to "transform" the future using `map` for instance.
If you have a `val resp: Future[Response] = ...`, if you want to get the status code, what you can do is `resp.map(response => response.statusCode)`. The type of the expression is `Future[Int]`

### Sequence the futures

Once you have your fonctions :

- `def getLocations(region: String, key: String): Future[List[(Int, Int, String)]]`
- `def anotherFunctionWhichReturnsAFuture(locations: List[(Int, Int, String)]): Future[Something]`

If you want to pass the result of the first function (`getLocations`) to the second one (`anotherFunctionWhichReturnsAFuture`) you have a problem because the types do not fit. You want to get rid of the future. To to that you can use `for`.

Here is an example :

```
for { 
    locations <- getLocations("Maine et Loire", "49")
    result <- anotherFunctionWhichReturnsAFuture(locations)
} yield result
```